# TypeError in returned value django

Tags: django, model

I have this property for my table:

```
@property
def commission_percent(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Data retrieval operation - no commit required
        cursor.execute('SELECT crowdfunding_offering.commission_percent FROM crowdfunding_offering WHERE crowdfunding_offering.id = %s ORDER BY crowdfunding_offering.id DESC LIMIT 1', (int(self.offering.id),))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        if not row is None:
            return row
        return 0
```

which returns `0.05`. It's going exactly how I expected it, but when I try to use the value to compute for another property like so:

```
def commission_due(self):
    if not self.commission_paid is None:
        return (self.invested * self.commission_percent) - self.commission_paid
    return self.invested * self.commission_percent
```

I get this error:

```
Exception Value:    can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'decimal.Decimal'
```

I tried changing `self.commission_percent` to `self.commission_percent()` but I get this error:

```
Exception Value:    'tuple' object is not callable
```

I don't know what to do, and this is all very new to me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply a string with a decimal the exception will be raised, you should do some debug process in which you print out the type of your varaibles for example,
instead of this

```
def commission_due(self):
    if not self.commission_paid is None:
        return (self.invested * self.commission_percent) - self.commission_paid
    return self.invested * self.commission_percent
```

do this

```
def commission_due(self):
    if not self.commission_paid is None:
        print("Type invested::", type(self.invested))
        print("Type commission_percent::", type(self.commission_percent))
        print("Type commission_paid::", type(self.commission_paid))
```

in that way you first see the types of your variables and if some of these variables are not decimal you parse it to decimal

the other error is because the function commission_percent returns a tuple, look a the following example

```
my_tuple = (1, 2, 4)
print(my_typle()) # -> it is wrong because the tuple is not callable instead do 
# this
my_tuple = (1, 2, 4)
print(my_typle) # -> it is the right way
```